# Get max value within PARTITON BY in CTE function

Tags: sql, sql-server, common-table-expression, window-functions

I'm struggling with log aggregation with window functions. I have table with columns

- Item (string)
- User (string)
- TimeStart (timestamp)

With a CTE, I'm trying to merge all entries within 5 min into one, to create a time interval. In C1 I'm looking for the start of next interval, C2 is grouping records into intervals. To this point it works fine.

When I selected C2 I got my data labeled with group ID. But when I'm trying to catch max time from my group as TimeEnd in C3 I got messed data that is useless. As I understand `OVER PARTITION BY` it should be a simple comparison of TimeStart values within partition and return of MAX, but instead of I get messed group IDs, and TimeEnds

Code below, SQL Server Express:

```
WITH C1 AS
(
    SELECT 
        Item,
        User,
        TimeStart,
        CASE 
            WHEN DATEDIFF(MINUTE, LAG(TimeStart) OVER (PARTITION BY Item, User ORDER BY TimeStart), TimeStart) < 5
                THEN 0
                ELSE 1
        END AS isstart
    FROM
        Log 
),
C2 AS 
(
    SELECT 
        *,
        SUM(isstart) OVER (ORDER BY TimeStart ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING) AS grp
    FROM 
        C1
),
C3 AS
(
    SELECT 
        *, 
        MAX(TimeStart) OVER (PARTITION BY grp) AS TimeEnd 
    FROM 
        C2
)
SELECT * 
FROM C3
```

Could you explain to me what happened here and how to solve it?

PS: I could use `GROUP BY` clause but I'll lose non aggregated columns.

Comment: A [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) would be useful.

Comment: 1: C1 does not seem to "merge all entries within 5 min into one", it merely looks at 1 previous record. If all of your entries within `Item,User` sequence are within 5 min of each other then `isstart` will never be 1.
2: C2 - I think you need to add `Item,User` to the `ORDER BY`

Comment: `TIMESTAMP` in SQL Server does ***NOT*** store the date and time - you're aware of that, right?? It's a **binary, system-controlled** counter and has been renamed to `ROWVERSION` (which is much closer to what it really is). If you want date and time - use `DATETIME2(n)` instead ...

Comment: You need a partitioning clause in the second CTE `SUM(isstart) OVER (PARTITION BY Item, [User] ORDER BY TimeStart ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING)` and then again in the third `(PARTITION BY Item, [User], grp)` (although that one could use nnormal aggregation. Sample data and expected output would help immensely

Comment: @Alex - you are right. C1 is looking at the previous row to check if it is in 5 min range. In this table, I have logged all user requests to powerbi server so for 1 usage of report usually is 10-50 rows within 2-5[s] so this is kind of filtering. Your solution with C2 is working thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @Alex, I got this solution:

```
WITH C1 AS
(
    SELECT 
        Item,
        User,
        TimeStart,
        CASE 
            WHEN DATEDIFF(MINUTE, LAG(TimeStart) OVER (PARTITION BY Item, User ORDER BY TimeStart), TimeStart) < 5
                THEN 0
                ELSE 1
        END AS isstart
    FROM
        Log 
),
C2 AS 
(
    SELECT 
        *,
        SUM(isstart) OVER ( ORDER BY ItemPath,UserName,TimeStart 
                              ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING) as grp
    FROM 
        C1
),
C3 AS(
SELECT *, MAX(TimeStart) OVER (PARTITION BY grp ) AS [TimeEnd] FROM C2
)
SELECT * FROM C3
       where isstart=1
       ORDER BY grp
```

The problem was in second CTE with the wrong ORDER of rows.

Also I send preview of output data
[Output data preview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k6L7q.png)